# Using modulo and integer division to confirm an account number

Tags: java

I am new to Java and currently working on a small class assignment. The question is as follows:

> Write a program that determines whether a bank account number with 10 digits or fewer passes a validation test; it requires that we extract the digits, right to left by:
>
> - Using the modulo operator to extract the right most digit
> - Using integer division to remove the right-most digit from the account number to obtain a new number without it.
>   Beginning with the 2nd right-most digit, moving right to left, double every other digit. If it produces a value greater than 9, subtract 9 from that value.
> - Form the sum of all products(new digits) and the unchanged digits.
> - if the sum doesn't end in 0, its invalid.
>
> Check the validity of 5113 4765 12 and 65 1234 1234

Here is my code:

```
long account = Long.parseLong(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Enter account number: " ));
int sum = 0;
long digit;
//5113476512
//6512341234
String str_number = String.valueOf(account);

digit = account % 10;
account /= 10;

for(int i = str_number.length() -2; i >= 0; i --){
  digit = account % 10;

  account /= 10;

  // account%=10;
  // sum += digit;
  digit *= 2;
  if (digit > 9){
    digit -= 9;
  }
  sum += digit;
}
// for(int x = 0; x < digit.length; x ++){
//   sum += digit[x];
// }
if (sum % 10 != 0){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account number invalid");
}
else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account number valid");
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sum);
```

But I feel it doesn't follow the requirements and might not be correct. Only one of the account numbers returns valid although I'm not sure if that is supposed to be so or not. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Weird that the instructions tell you to extract the right-most digit and then don't do anything else with it.

Comment: Related - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Comment: @user16320675 I did double every other digit ```digit *= 2``` or do you mean double the account number itself?

Comment: @user16320675
 I also am not sure on how to go about the sum of all digits. When I tried adding the new digits to the account number then the validation proved both account numbers as invalid. Ignoring the unclear instructions, how would you go about writing this program?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I'll try that now. I changed the code into a while loop, using while account > 0 and changed it to every other number: ```if (i % 2 == 0){
        digit*=2;
      }
      sum += digit;

      if (digit > 9){
        digit -= 9;
      }
      sum += digit;```
I still need to understand what is meant by the sum.

Comment: Since the lecturer has refused to explain further. I'm going to leave it as sum += digit, where sum is initialized to 0. One of the account numbers returns valid this way.

Comment: @user16320675
 Yes, I have removed that already. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation using a boolean flag to detect *the other* number shows that both account numbers are invalid:

```java
public static boolean isValid(long acc) {
    System.out.print(acc + " -> "); // debug print
    int sum = 0;
    boolean other = false;
    while (acc > 0) {
        int digit = (int) (acc % 10);
        acc /= 10;
        if (other) {
            digit *= 2;
            if (digit > 9) digit -= 9;
        }
        System.out.print(digit + " "); // debug print
        sum += digit;
        other = !other;
    }
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum); // debug print
    return sum % 10 == 0;
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(isValid(5113476512L));
System.out.println(isValid(6512341234L));
```

Output:

```
5113476512 -> 2 2 5 3 7 8 3 2 1 1 sum = 34
false
6512341234 -> 4 6 2 2 4 6 2 2 5 3 sum = 36
false
```